# Проблема по php

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть ссылка `mysite.ru/index.php?fun=dual`, нажав на которую в базе к одному значению прибавляется 1.

Одновременно с этой ссылкой в странице `index.php` я вывожу значение из базы (то значение, к которому прибавится 1). В коде у меня написано, что если существует `get fun` и `get fun==dual`, то тогда в базе к значению прибавляется 1, и в то же время, после нажатия на ссылку, я вывожу это значение из базы, но оно не меняется. Если на эту ссылку нажать ещё раз, то уже в базу идёт +1, но видно на этой странице старое значение.

Например: в базе значение 0, и на странице `index.php` выводится это значение, то есть 0. Там же внизу есть ссылка, нажав на которую в базе к этому значению делается +1. Итак, после нажатия на ссылку на странице опять видно значение 0 (но если в этот момент открыть базу – там значение будет 1). Потом, если ещё раз нажать на эту ссылку, то уже на странице видно значение 1 (хотя открыв в этот момент базу, там значение 2), и всё время после нажатия на ссылку есть такая разница.

Как исправить эту разницу?

Comment: Вы бы свой код привели. а так сначала выполняем update, потом select и все

Comment: Mike сегодня код привести не смогу комп далеко, а пока использовать update это идея спасибо завтраже проверю

Comment: Нажатие на ссылку обновляет страницу, или делается ajax запрос?

Comment: Нажатие на ссылку не обновляет страницу и ajax нету так как в первом случае это выглядет не красиво а во вторых сайт для телефонов

Comment: Мне нужно чтоб после нажатие на ссылку сразуже выводилось значение из базы а не старое. Я понимаю что можно сделать с ajax но мне нужно как то на php

Comment: Первый комментарий я проверю завтра атак если поможите буду благодарен

Comment: Большое спасибо я очень благодарен

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала обновляйте данные, затем выводите их.

А лучше, приняв посетителя с `?fun=dual` обновите базу, и, ничего не показывая ещё, сразу же [перекиньте](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) его на эту же страницу, но без параметров. И тогда ему покажет уже обновлённый счётчик, и обновление (Refresh/Reload) страницы, не накрутит счётик лишний раз.

Ваш `index.php` может выглядеть примерно так:

```
<?php // это самое начало. Смотрим, с чем пришёл юзер
if( isset($_GET['fun'])  &&  $_GET['fun']==='dual') {
  // обновляем значение в БД
  MySQL: UPDATE ....

  // и сразу редирект на эту же страницу, но без параметров
  header('Location: http://mysite.ru/index.php');
  exit();
}

// теперь получаем данные для вывода страницы
// MySQL: SELECT .....
// $counter = ...;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="Ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
...
Счётчик: <?php echo $counter; ?>
```